batched PyTorch tensor indexing
I have a source tensor of size (3, 2) and an index tensor of size (3, 3) containing integer values 0, 1, or 2. In pytorch I can do tensor indexing source[index] to get a tensor of size (3, 3, 2). Example:
source: 
tensor([[1, 6],
        [2, 3],
        [8, 0]])

index: 
tensor([[2, 1, 2],
        [1, 1, 2],
        [2, 0, 0]])

source[index]: 
tensor([[[8, 0],
         [2, 3],
         [8, 0]],

        [[2, 3],
         [2, 3],
         [8, 0]],

        [[8, 0],
         [1, 6],
         [1, 6]]])

I want to do the above operation but batched.
For example with a batch size of 2:
source shape --> (2, 3, 2)
index shape --> (2, 3, 3)
batched source[index] shape --> (2, 3, 3, 2)
I can easily do this with a loop but I want to know if it can be done efficiently with torch.gather or some other built-in?

I was able to achieve the desired effect with some reshaping:
source = torch.randint(0, 10, (2, 3, 2))
index = torch.randint(0, 3, (2, 3, 3))
index = index.flatten(-2)
index = index[:, :, None].expand(-1, -1, 2)
out = source.gather(1, index).view(2, 3, 3, 2)

